# Raise "No records Inserted/Found" Exception in Insert Statement

Tags: oracle11g

I have the following code snippet in ORACLE 11G

```
BEGIN 
  FOR LOOP IN (SELECT DISTINCT TIME_PERIOD FROM TABLEA)
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO TABLEB 
      (SELECT SUBITEM, LOC 
       FROM TABLEC 
       WHERE TABLEC.ITEM = TABLEA.ITEM);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I want to raise an exception when for a particular Item there are no Subitems in Table C and hence no records inserted in TableB.

Block should verify a particular Item,inserts the data if subitems exist or else raise the exception(user defined exception where data gets inserted into ERROR table) for the particular item and proceed forward.

**P.S:** I just want to know where and how should I raise the exception in the FOR loop.Insert code into Error Table is not required.

Do not want to use Cursors.

Help is much appreciated.!

---

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understood the question.

As you didn't provide test case, I did that myself.

```
SQL> create table tablea (item number, time_period number);

Table created.

SQL> create table tableb(subitem number, loc varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table tablec (item number, subitem number, loc varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into tablea values (1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tablec values (1, 1, 'a');

1 row created.
```

Code you posted is invalid, so - I modified it so that it actually does *something*. `SQL%ROWCOUNT` returns number of rows affected, so I'm checking whether `INSERT` inserted anything or not. If not, raise an error and further execution is terminated.

The first execution is successful as there's match between ITEM values in both TABLEA and TABLEC:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select distinct item, time_period from tablea) loop
  3      insert into tableb (subitem, loc)
  4        select c.subitem, c.loc
  5          from tablec c
  6          where c.item = cur_r.item;
  7
  8      if sql%rowcount = 0 then
  9         raise_application_error(-20000, 'Nothing has been inserted for TABLEA.ITEM = ' || cur_r.item);
 10      end if;
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tableb;

   SUBITEM LOC
---------- --------------------
         1 a

SQL>
```

Now, let's insert ITEM = 2 into TABLEA, which doesn't have a pair in TABLEC and will, therefore, raise an error:

```
SQL> insert into tablea values (2, 2);

1 row created.

SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select distinct item, time_period from tablea) loop
  3      insert into tableb (subitem, loc)
  4        select c.subitem, c.loc
  5          from tablec c
  6          where c.item = cur_r.item;
  7
  8      if sql%rowcount = 0 then
  9         raise_application_error(-20000, 'Nothing has been inserted for TABLEA.ITEM = ' || cur_r.item);
 10      end if;
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Nothing has been inserted for TABLEA.ITEM = 2
ORA-06512: at line 9
```